# Benefit of setting request attributes in a web application

Tags: java, http, servlets, request

I was working on a web service and while reading about HTTP Requests and Responses and Headers, I came across the method `setAttribute(String s, Object o)` in the ServletRequest class.

The problem I am facing is in trying to understand, why will someone set the attribute for a request after it has been received by my servlet. Setting the attributes and parameters on the front end is logical as it helps in sending information from the front end to the middle tier, but what do we get by setting an attribute in the middle tier itself.

Answer (score 1):

Request attributes are accessible on the jsp templating context so you can decorate a request with an error messages or anything you want to template, for example:

```
${requestScope.Error_Message}
```

If you are using plain JSP, as opposed to something like spring mvc, decorating the request with attributes may just  be the easiest way to get data for templating in the jsp.

You may also have a chain of servlet filters that decorate requests in various ways before you get to the final handler that sends a response to the client.

And, yes requests are sometimes forwarded to other servlets for processing.  In this case decorating the request with attributes provides a way of communicating between your endpoints.

However, it's a useful pattern whenever and wherever you need to save some state over the lifespan of a single request.

Answer (score 0):

A request may not complete with one cycle. That particular request may be forwarded to another request to fulfill the service. While forwarding the request if you want to add additional inputs, that's the way.

In short, *to exchange information between requests.*